# how to test a specific algorithm using tcrypt.ko module in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, cryptography, aes, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have noticed that there is a test module(tcrypt.c) in linux kernel crypto subsytem. I am able to use this module for any bench marking scenarios like aes with following command "modprobe tcrypt sec=1 mode=200"

But I am not able to test the individual algorithms using the same like below

"modprobe tcrypt  mode=10 "

It throws an error "alg: skcipher: Failed to load transform for ctr(aes): -22"

when mode value is 0 it executes to test every algorithm till mode value reaches 200,almost every scenario it fails with similar type of error for respective algorithms like hash/hmac etc.

Please can any one let me know how this issue can be addressed?

BR,
& sanumala

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

Loading the transforms depends on your current kernel build. Tcrypt tries all combinations of the algorithms available from a vanilla kernel source. From what I see, you don't have the CTR mode available for AES. You might have to build a custom kernel.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/crypto/tcrypt.c#L434

Answer (score 0):

`tcrypt.c` is out of date in latest kernel. Please make sure your kernel is capable of cyrpto, i.e. `/proc/crypto`

```
name         : __ctr(aes)
driver       : cryptd(__ctr-aes-ce)
module       : kernel


name         : __cts(cbc(aes))
driver       : cryptd(__cts-cbc-aes-ce)
module       : kernel


name         : __xts(aes)
driver       : cryptd(__xts-aes-ce)
module       : kernel


name         : __cbc(aes)
driver       : cryptd(__cbc-aes-ce)
module       : kernel


name         : __ecb(aes)
driver       : cryptd(__ecb-aes-ce)
module       : kernel


name         : jitterentropy_rng
driver       : jitterentropy_rng
module       : kernel


name         : aes
driver       : aes-arm64
module       : kernel


name         : sha224
driver       : sha224-arm64-neon
module       : kernel


name         : sha256
driver       : sha256-arm64-neon
module       : kernel


name         : sha224
driver       : sha224-arm64
module       : kernel


name         : sha256
driver       : sha256-arm64
module       : kernel


name         : xts(aes)
driver       : xts-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : ctr(aes)
driver       : ctr-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : cts(cbc(aes))
driver       : cts-cbc-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : cbc(aes)
driver       : cbc-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : ecb(aes)
driver       : ecb-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : cbcmac(aes)
driver       : cbcmac-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : xcbc(aes)
driver       : xcbc-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : cmac(aes)
driver       : cmac-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : __xts(aes)
driver       : __xts-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : ctr(aes)
driver       : ctr-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : __ctr(aes)
driver       : __ctr-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : __cts(cbc(aes))
driver       : __cts-cbc-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : __cbc(aes)
driver       : __cbc-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : __ecb(aes)
driver       : __ecb-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : ccm(aes)
driver       : ccm-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : aes
driver       : aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : gcm(aes)
driver       : gcm-aes-ce
module       : kernel


name         : ghash
driver       : ghash-ce
module       : kernel


name         : ghash
driver       : ghash-neon
module       : kernel


name         : sha256
driver       : sha256-ce
module       : kernel


name         : sha224
driver       : sha224-ce
module       : kernel


name         : sha1
driver       : sha1-ce
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_nopr_hmac_sha256
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_nopr_hmac_sha512
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_nopr_hmac_sha384
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_nopr_hmac_sha1
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_pr_hmac_sha256
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_pr_hmac_sha512
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_pr_hmac_sha384
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : drbg_pr_hmac_sha1
module       : kernel


name         : stdrng
driver       : ansi_cprng
module       : kernel


name         : crct10dif
driver       : crct10dif-generic
module       : kernel


name         : crc32c
driver       : crc32c-generic
module       : kernel


name         : zlib-deflate
driver       : zlib-deflate-scomp
module       : kernel


name         : deflate
driver       : deflate-scomp
module       : kernel


name         : deflate
driver       : deflate-generic
module       : kernel


name         : aes
driver       : aes-generic
module       : kernel


name         : sha224
driver       : sha224-generic
module       : kernel


name         : sha256
driver       : sha256-generic
module       : kernel


name         : sha1
driver       : sha1-generic
module       : kernel


name         : ecb(cipher_null)
driver       : ecb-cipher_null
module       : kernel


name         : digest_null
driver       : digest_null-generic
module       : kernel


name         : compress_null
driver       : compress_null-generic
module       : kernel


name         : cipher_null
driver       : cipher_null-generic
module       : kernel


name         : rsa
driver       : rsa-generic
module       : kernel


name         : dh
driver       : dh-generic
module       : kernel
```

Take `ecb(aes)` as example,

```
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/smp.h>
#include <crypto/skcipher.h>
#include <crypto/akcipher.h>
#include <crypto/acompress.h>
#include <crypto/rng.h>
#include <crypto/drbg.h>
#include <crypto/kpp.h>
#include <crypto/internal/simd.h>
#include <crypto/aead.h>
#include <crypto/hash.h>
#include <linux/crypto.h>
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/err.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/fips.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/scatterlist.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/zlib.h>
#include <linux/once.h>
#include <linux/random.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

/* tie all data structures together */
struct skcipher_def {
    struct scatterlist sg;
    struct crypto_skcipher *tfm;
    struct skcipher_request *req;
    struct crypto_wait wait;
};

/* Perform cipher operation */
static unsigned int test_skcipher_encdec(struct skcipher_def *sk,
                     int enc)
{
    int rc;

    if (enc)
        rc = crypto_wait_req(crypto_skcipher_encrypt(sk->req), &sk->wait);
    else
        rc = crypto_wait_req(crypto_skcipher_decrypt(sk->req), &sk->wait);

    if (rc)
            pr_info("skcipher encrypt returned with result %d\n", rc);

    return rc;
}

/* Initialize and trigger cipher operation */
static int test_skcipher(void)
{
    struct skcipher_def sk;
    struct crypto_skcipher *skcipher = NULL;
    struct skcipher_request *req = NULL;
    char *scratchpad = NULL;
    char *ivdata = NULL;
    unsigned char key[32];
    int ret = -EFAULT;

    skcipher = crypto_alloc_skcipher("ecb-aes-ce", 0, 0);
    if (IS_ERR(skcipher)) {
        pr_info("could not allocate skcipher handle\n");
        return PTR_ERR(skcipher);
    }

    req = skcipher_request_alloc(skcipher, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!req) {
        pr_info("could not allocate skcipher request\n");
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto out;
    }

    skcipher_request_set_callback(req, CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG,
                      crypto_req_done,
                      &sk.wait);

    /* AES 256 with random key */
    get_random_bytes(&key, 32);
    if (crypto_skcipher_setkey(skcipher, key, 32)) {
        pr_info("key could not be set\n");
        ret = -EAGAIN;
        goto out;
    }

    /* IV will be random */
    ivdata = kmalloc(16, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!ivdata) {
        pr_info("could not allocate ivdata\n");
        goto out;
    }
    get_random_bytes(ivdata, 16);

    /* Input data will be random */
    scratchpad = kmalloc(16, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!scratchpad) {
        pr_info("could not allocate scratchpad\n");
        goto out;
    }
    get_random_bytes(scratchpad, 16);

    sk.tfm = skcipher;
    sk.req = req;

    /* We encrypt one block */
    sg_init_one(&sk.sg, scratchpad, 16);
    skcipher_request_set_crypt(req, &sk.sg, &sk.sg, 16, ivdata);
    crypto_init_wait(&sk.wait);

    /* encrypt data */
    ret = test_skcipher_encdec(&sk, 1);
    if (ret)
        goto out;

    pr_info("Encryption triggered successfully\n");

out:
    if (skcipher)
        crypto_free_skcipher(skcipher);
    if (req)
        skcipher_request_free(req);
    if (ivdata)
        kfree(ivdata);
    if (scratchpad)
        kfree(scratchpad);
    return ret;
}


static int __init test_init(void)
{
    printk("info: init test\n");
    test_skcipher();
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_exit(void)
{
    printk("info: exit test\n");
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");
MODULE_AUTHOR("author@author.com");
```

`skcipher` is used because algorithm ecb is bonding to this type in this kernel.